# Why does Run-Time Error 1004 appear when clicking on ActiveX Button

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner in Excel VBA Coding so pardon me if I committed a basic error.

I have an ActiveX button which brings up a UserForm for the user to key in data which will then be entered onto a separate sheet in the same workbook. After finishing the code for the UserForm, I am not able to access the form via the ActiveX button. It brings up the Run-Time error 1004. Can someone please help me with this?

This is the code for my ActiveX Button:

```
Private Sub cmdNewMLData_Click()

frmMasterListEntry.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: Something wrong with the UserForm code more likely.

Comment: I agree with @Davesexcel. To check, you can just add a brake point in the first line of code that is executed in the UserForm (usually within `UserForm_Initialize`) and see if the brake point is reached after you click the button.

Comment: Can you manually launch the form? I mean, selecting it and pressing F5 (in VBE, of course...).

Comment: @Davesexcel, Michael Wycisk and FaneDuru, Thanks for pointing me in the direction that there is an error in my UserForm code. I found out that one of my code was referencing the wrong worksheet. It has been resolved now.